# Get Data from table for 2 fields mapped with same mapping table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. **Location** & **Route**. In route table, I have `from` & `to` fields both are mapped to Location table.

**Location** : `location_id`, `location_name`
**Route** : `route_id`, `route_from`, `route_to`

Since both `route_from` & `route_to` mapped with `location` table, simply joining the table is not giving me result. Tried below query but not able to fetch desired result. How can I get name of both `route_from` & `route_to` by mapping with `location` table? Help me guys!

```
SELECT * FROM bus_route b, bus_location a
WHERE a.bus_location_id = b.route_from AND a.bus_location_id = b.route_to
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform joining of location table for each dependent column and can select the required column values by replacing * from select query with required columns

```
SELECT * FROM bus_route b 
  INNER JOIN bus_location a ON a.bus_location_id = b.route_from 
  INNER JOIN bus_location c ON c.bus_location_id = b.route_to
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `AND` use `OR` in your query.

```
SELECT * FROM bus_route b, bus_location a

WHERE a.bus_location_id = b.route_from OR a.bus_location_id = b.route_to
```

Comment: It worked but I'm getting two rows which is not I wanted. I accepted Sandesh Jain's answer which is what I needed! But still, thanks a lot of your answer.